# 'for follow up' or 'for following up'

Tags: verbs, nouns

I was wondering why in this sentence

> I can enlist her support for follow up in my weekly meeting tomorrow

“follow up” was used instead of “following up”?

Answer (score 3):

*Follow up* has been used since the early twentieth century as a noun, the act of "following up".

> In case a reply is received to a letter marked for follow-up, before the follow-up date arrives, the file clerk knows that a tickler has been made when she sees the date notation in the upper right hand corner of the filed letter. —[American Gas Engineering Journal](https://books.google.com/books?id=wvHmAAAAMAAJ&q=%22for+follow+up%22&dq=%22for+follow+up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjhZC43obNAhXJ5oMKHaKSBXk4ChDoAQgmMAM), 1926

(A 'tickler' in office contexts means a formal reminder of something to be done in the future: it 'tickles' the reader's memory.)

Note that the phrase is employed both as the nominal object of the preposition *for* and as an attributive nominal modifying *date*.

Note, too, that the phrase is written here with a hyphen, *follow-up*, to signal that this is not an ordinary verbal use. This sort of hyphenation is falling out of use, but I recommend it as a valuable courtesy to the reader.